# Need to use excel sumifs with OR and exclude 3 values and sum the rest

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sumifs

In the below formula I need to sum the numbers if they fall with H:H( 5 values mentioned) and same way N:N( if one among them is found ) and K:K(exclude all those 3 and add for the rest)

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Order Summary OPAL'!$R:$R,'Order Summary OPAL'!$H:$H,{"XBX","XB1","NSW","IA","PS4"},'Order Summary OPAL'!$N:$N,{"None","*FA samples","abc"}'Order Summary OPAL'!$K:$K,OR({"<>Kit Complete","<>Delivered","<>Running"})))
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can only do two arrays.  You would need to sum when both N and H meet the requirements then subtract where N and H and K meet the OR requirements.  But that make 3 and you cannot use SUMIFS for that.

You will need to change to SUMPRODUCT, but since it is an array type formula it should be limited to the data set.

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Order Summary OPAL'!$R$1:$R$100,
  (ISNUMBER(MATCH('Order Summary OPAL'!$H$1:$H$100,{"XBX","XB1","NSW","IA","PS4"},0)))*
  (ISNUMBER(MATCH('Order Summary OPAL'!$N$1:$N$100,{"None","*FA samples","abc"},0)))*
  (ISERROR(MATCH('Order Summary OPAL'!$K$1:$K$100,{"Kit Complete","Delivered","Running"},0))))
```

Comment: Looks like this formula is not working and giving a wrong value

Comment: Without test data I cannot test to find out why.

Comment: Is there a way where I can share you the file